# Custom Control referenced by 'RequiredFieldValidator' cannot be validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, requiredfieldvalidator, validation-controls

**Question:** How do I correctly extend a custom control to work with the RequiredFieldValidator? I've read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310145/en-us), but trying to implement it didn't solve the problem for me.
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
 <%@ Register src="DynamicGenerator/Controls/ReferenceControl.ascx" tagname="ReferenceControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
    <uc1:ReferenceControl ID="SelectAgreement" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="SelectAgreement" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select an agreement!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Code behind:

```
[ValidationProperty("ConceptDefinitionId")]
public partial class ReferenceSelector : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IReference
{
   //lots of other stuff
 public string ConceptDefinitionId
        {
            get { return ReferenceControl.ConceptDefinitionId ?? ""; }
            set { ReferenceControl.ConceptDefinitionId = value; }
        }
}
```

Loading this page gives me the following error:

Control 'SelectAgreement' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'RequiredFieldValidator' cannot be validated.

stacktrace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'SelectAgreement' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'RequiredFieldValidator' cannot be validated.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String name, String propertyName) +8739685
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +40
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.get_PropertiesValid() +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Comment: Your code looks right to me.  I got to this question having the same problem, except I was missing the `ValidationPropertyAttribute`.  As soon as I added that _(my property is read-only and returns `int`, for comparison)_ it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to place the `RequiredFieldValidator` inside the UserControl and validate a specific control like a `TextBox` or `DropDown`, since validators are allowed only in the same naming container and in your case the UserControl is a different container so this won't work.

Another way could be using [ValidationPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.validationpropertyattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using a ValidationPropertyAttribute (see the codebehind), but I suppose I am using it in the wrong way?

Comment: Try changing the `EnableClientScript` property

Comment: Tried setting it both true and false on the RequiredFieldEditor with no result.

Comment: If you want to validate two instances of your custom `UserControl` against each other you cannot (trivially) do so by putting the validator(s) inside the UserControl.  The best solution in that case is to use `ValidationPropertyAttribute`.  Whichever property of your custom control you specify is passed through to the validator with `.ToString()`.  (My property is a read-only `int`.)